# Don't seem to have control over a class tag in css

Tags: html, css

I have a class declared as an error catch for specific input:

```
'<span class="catch">Error caught</span>';
```

I styled it a bit at the end of my tags:

```
.catch{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 150px 0px 0px 35px ;
}
```

The margin attributes are just place holders, but I am attempting to move the text down to the bottom of the this form, but can only control the x-axis, not the y-axis.  Is there ways around this?  Here is my form code:

```
#main{ 
    width: 375px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background: url(images/formheader.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    margin:200px auto; 
    z-index: 1;
```

}

There is additional css if I need to provide more info.

EDITED:

```
#main{ 
   width: 875px; 
   height: 350px; 
   background: url(images/form.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
   margin:250px auto; 
   z-index: 1; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s hard to tell what you want to do exactly without seeing the html, but if you want `.catch` to appear at the bottom of `#main` you can use something like:

```
.catch{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#main{ 
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100px;    /* example to avoid content of #main to be under .catch */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`<span>` is an inline element and only x-axis margins work on inline elements.
Set  `.catch` to `display:block;`

Based on @Czechnology comment, changing the `<span>` to a `<div>` makes more sense than taking an inline element and setting it to block.

Comment: It's better to change a `<span>` to a `<div>` than setting it to be a block element.

Comment: I changed it to: '<div="catch">Caught</div>';

and added: display:block to the newly changed #catch{  } tag but it still stays in the same place...am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I completely agree, but I was answering the question, not rethinking how @user699378 was developing. Will update answer though. But now that I am thinking through, it could make sense if @user699378 was developing for multiple screen sizes and needed to reflow the span.

Comment: `<div class="catch">Caught</div>` and you would target it in CSS with `.catch{}`. Because it is a `<div>`, which is already a block level element, it does not need `display:block;`

Comment: hmmm changing it to a div still seems to not allow control over the y-axis.

Comment: We might not have enough information then. Can you edit your question with what else is inside `#main`?

Comment: I meant the HTML, not the CSS. Sorry.

Comment: Keep the <div class="catch">Caught</div> at the end within form and give it position:absolute;bottom:0 and then give the form position:relative. I think this may work.